# Browser Compatibility issue (while using jQuery, css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

Following is the url of the site: http://bit.ly/mykwikweb

Website loads some components in IE, others not working in Mozilla, Opera, Chrome or safari
Even the alignment changes with browser.
I have used CSS, Jquery and some of the AJAX calls.
I was wondering which mode to use?
Strict or Quirks modes?

Comment: It's *never* a good idea to build a website against quirks mode.

Comment: should at least validate the page as first troubleshooting step!

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan: So shall we exclude the <!DOCTYPE html> for the same?

Comment: @charlietfl: can you suggest some validation tools, i already checked w3c online Markup Validation Service

Comment: http://csslint.net and http://jslint.net

Comment: you need a doctype... read up on quirks mode

Comment: @charlietfl: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: A valid doctype will fix quirks mode issue, remove the comments on the one you have and start from there, pull the scripts to external file, or wrap in CDATA comments to make validation esier and make sure you don't have broken tags in w3c validator after all that. It's a web dev site, assume they will want 100% validation

Comment: @charlietfl, make that into an Answer.

Comment: @Kalpesh ~ Yeap, the HTML5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`) should do really nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS properties will be browser dependent.so check your CSS properties wheather it supports only IE.

Comment: This answer is best served as a comment in the Question area since it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A valid doctype will fix quirks mode issue. Remove the comments on the one you have and start from there, pull the scripts to external file, or wrap in CDATA comments to make validation easier and make sure you don't have broken tags in w3c validator after all that. It's a web dev site, assume they will want 100% validation

jQUery does not support quirks mode. It is perfectly acceptable having script in the page, the only reason I suggested external file is to simplify validation since you seem to be having troubles